# cURL error 60: SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name. Inter-project communication

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-8, drush, ddev

So I'm still in the process of updating a Drupal 7 site to 8 using drush and ddev.
After running the import, I get an error with upgrade_d7_file.
I've tried to install a certificate using this article:
https://www.ddev.com/ddev-local/ddev-local-trusted-https-certificates/

However still get the error, any ideas?

```
ddev exec drush migrate-import --all
ddev exec drush mmsg upgrade_d7_file

cURL error 60: SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name
'drupal7migration2.ddev.site'
(see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
(https://drupal7migration2.ddev.site//sites/default/files/Virtual%20Challenges%20%28Results%20and%2
0PBs%29%2020200709.xlsx)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you want one DDEV-Local project to talk to another using https, curl on the client side has to trust the server side that you're talking to. There are two ways to do this:

1. (built-in, no changes needed): Use `ddev-<projectname>-web` (the container name) as the target hostname in the URL. For example in your case, use `curl https://ddev-drupal7migration2-web`. This hostname is already trusted among various ddev projects.
2. (requires docker-compose.*.yaml): If you want to use the real full FQDN of the target project (https://drupal7migration2.ddev.site in your case) then you'll need to add that as an external_link in the *client* project's .ddev. So add a file named .ddev/docker-compose.external_links.yaml in the client side (migration1?) project, with these contents:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  web:
    external_links:
    - "ddev-router:drupal7migration2.ddev.site"
```

That will tell Docker to route requests to "drupal7migration2.ddev.site" to the ddev-router, and your container and curl trust it (it has that name in its cert list).